# FULLTEXT search with a multi-language column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, internationalization, full-text-search

Is there a way to use FULLTEXT in a multi-language table without giving each language its own column?

I have one column I need to search, but the language in that column varies:

```
ProductID    int
Description  nvarchar(max)
Language     char(2)
```

`Language` can be one of: `en`, `de`, `it`, `kr`, `th`

Currently I build a concordance and use that for searching. But this is only for English, German and Italian, and even for those it doesn't support stemming. Everything else uses `LIKE '%searchterm%'`, and I'm trying to improve on that.

I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Instead of a separate column per language, if you know which rows contain which language you could create an indexed view filtered to include only rows of a single langauge per language and FTI each of those.  You'll need to query each view individually though.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from the Microsoft reference on [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx):

> For non-BLOB and non-XML columns
>   containing text data in multiple
>   languages, or for cases when the
>   language of the text stored in the
>   column is unknown, it might be
>   appropriate for you to use the neutral
>   (0x0) language resource. However,
>   first you should understand the
>   possible consequences of using the
>   neutral (0x0) language resource. For
>   information about the possible
>   solutions and consequences of using
>   the neutral (0x0) language resource,
>   see [Best Practices for Choosing a
>   Language When Creating a Full-Text
>   Index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142507.aspx).

Comment: Those pages basically say: no.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old question, but I just encountered it.

One approach I have seen is to use an XML column and specify the `xml:lang` attribute. As mentioned in [CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx).

> For documents stored in XML- or BLOB-type columns, the language
>   encoding within the document will be used at indexing time. For
>   example, in XML columns, the xml:lang attribute in XML documents will
>   identify the language. At query time, the value previously specified
>   in language_term becomes the default language used for full-text
>   queries unless language_term is specified as part of a full-text
>   query.

The main downside of this approach is that it changes the data type to XML, but it seemed to work fine for our needs at the time.

Answer (score 3):

I am using views for 20+ languages. Works fine for querying (if a little complex to select the correct view to use in sprocs). However, inserts and updates on the underlying table get clobbered as the plan seems to need to include a check on every ft view even with no change tracking.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working elsewhere now, but you never know what might come up tomorrow :)